# Hot reload is duplicating websockets

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am creating a react app and using npm to hot reload the page on save. I am also connecting to a server through **socket.io** and it works great except that when I save the file and it reloads, it duplicates the socket and creates multiple active socket connections from a single page. Can I close the socket on reload somehow so that I keep only one socket active every time it reloads?

Comment: Is your problem that the socket connect persist upon exiting the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `useRef` when creating the `socketIOClient`. `useRef` is used to persist values between re-renders
E.g. -

```
const socket = useRef(socketIOClient(ENDPOINT))
```